# exporting XMI file from StarUML 2.5

Tags: export, uml, xmi, staruml

I have StarUML v-2.5 installed in my pc, I need to export my project to a XMI file, in a previous version I did it in a very easy way, now, in the 2.5 version I dont know where to do it. It's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you first have to add that capability to StarUML via an extension.

Tools->Extension Manager....

In the resulting dialog, there are 2 tabs - "Registry" and "Installed". I believe the "Registry" tab should be the one selected by default, and that is what you want. In the list below the tabs, There should be an "XMI" item.  Click on the "Install" button next to it.  Once it's successful, "Close" the dialog box.

To export your project, go to:

File->Export->XMI Export (v2.1)...

Comment: yes, you're right, I did it of this way. But it exports to XML v2.1 and I need it in 1.x so I had to install an older version of StarUml...But thank you very much

Comment: I am confused. I thought that xmi was the implied standard for importing / exporting structures from one editor to the next. Is that not the case anymore, or did StarUML just drop the ball here?