# Is it possible to export files from StarUML software as *.uml file? Or at least convert *.mdj files to *.uml files somehow?

Tags: uml, software-design, flowchart, project-planning

I've created some flowcharts in the software StarUML. I currently have the free evaluation version, and don't plan on upgrading, as I have found an open source UML software that works much better and feels easier to use imo. Trying to see if there is anyway to export the files from StarUML as something other than .mdj, as this file type is not supported by the new software tool, and it would be great if I didn't have to remake the flowcharts from scratch. The new tool I'm using is called draw.io. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Kind of annoying that a software called Star**UML** can't export .**UML** files. Learned this software in my software engineering capstone course for undergraduate compsci degree, starting to get the feeling that it's a bit of a dogwater program.

Tried looking for different extensions to export as .uml file. Couldn't find any. Tried using an extension to export the files as .xmi files, was successful in doing so, but this file was also not compatable with draw.io. Also looked for some way to convert .xmi files to .uml files with no success.

Comment: Not my area but see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069033/exporting-xmi-file-from-staruml-2-5

Comment: There is no standard for UML files. The .uml extension corresponds to a proprietary format (https://www.solvusoft.com/en/file-extensions/file-extension-uml/ ) ewactly as .mdj. The only standardized format is xmi and it is somewhat annoying that a software that invested in the exotic uml format is not able to deal with a well documented xmi file...

Comment: @qwerty_so Thanks. I tried this extension already. I was able to export the file as an xmi, but it was incompatable with the new software I'm using unfortunately.